# Can a unique Twilio number be used simultaneously by multiple agents?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, voip, twilio-api

Yes, I know that it is possible to connect a client who calls to a number with multiple agents and whoever accepts the call can continue with it.

But I want to know if it's possible that 2 or more agents can call to **different** **users** at the same time with just one number and if they can receive calls at the same time from different clients, again with just one number.

[image]

I'm using Twilio, so if you please give me some orientation with the API, it would be awesome.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible the customer to agent mapping would be handled by your application logic.

An example is a customer calls to that one unique number, your application logic would do a CRM lookup to determine which agent attribute(s) to return with that customer (based on CallerID or
Information you collect from the customer using a Gather verb).

You could make use of a product like Twilio Task Router to efficiently route those calls (tasks) to the “available” agent(s) based on these returned agent attributes. Task Router would handle logic like if the agent is already on a call, they will not receive the new call but another capable agent can.